# Windows Application Recovery And Restart callback does not execute when std::abort is called

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am developing a native C++ application on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2019. In order to perform cleanup activities when my application crashes, I wish to use the [RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerapplicationrecoverycallback) function to register a recovery callback function.

The callback function works as expected in some situations, for example when dereferencing a nullptr.

My problem is that it is not executed when std::abort is called, for example as a result of an unhandled C++ exception.

Has anyone been able to make the RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback function with std::abort()?

Edit: As Remy Lebeau points out, std::abort() might be interpreted a clean shutdown, but still, with unhandled C++ exceptions, Windows Error Reporting is generating a dump, and I would expect the WER to call the recovery callback when it is registered.

Example code, where I expect "Callback called" to be printed, but it is not:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdexcept>

DWORD __stdcall Callback(PVOID)
{
    BOOL cancelled = FALSE;
    ApplicationRecoveryInProgress(&cancelled);
    printf("Callback called");
    ApplicationRecoveryFinished(TRUE);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback(Callback, nullptr, 5000, 0);
    throw std::runtime_error("Unhandled exception");
}
```

Comment: Can you please shpw what exactly your code does with an example?

Comment: WARR works only for *abnormal* terminations, ie when the process just disappears unexpectedly. `std::abort()` is an *immediate* termination, but it is not an *abnormal* termination. From Windows' perspective, the process exits cleanly. So there is no need for Windows to recover the process.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, nowadays by default `abort` is an *abnormal termination* via the [`__fastfail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/fastfail?view=vs-2019) intrinsic (e.g. software interrupt 0x29 with `FAST_FAIL_FATAL_APP_EXIT` in register `rcx`), which results in a `STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN` (0xC0000409) second-chance non-continuable exception with the parameter `FAST_FAIL_FATAL_APP_EXIT` (7), which tells WER that the process is corrupted and *minimal in-process actions* should be taken in response to the failure.

Comment: @ErykSun how `std::abort()` works is implementation-specific. `__fastfail` is specific to MSVC.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes, but unless otherwise clarified, it's reasonable to make an assumption that a question tagged as C++ and Windows is using VC++. The end result is likely the same here, but I haven't tested yet. I would not expect WER to call an in-process recovery function when the process is deemed so corrupted that "minimal in-process actions" should be taken.

Comment: I just tested and confirmed that WER does not call the in-process recovery callback after an `abort` that uses `__fastfail`, but it does handle the abnormal termination by restarting the application if it was registered for a restart via `RegisterApplicationRestart`.

Comment: @ErykSun “*it’s reasonable to make an assumption that a question tagged as C++ and Windows is using VC++*” - there are multiple C++ compilers for Windows. I’ve been making Windows apps in C++ for over 20 years and have rarely used VC++ for that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I understand all of that, Remy, but I still think it's reasonable to assume VC++ is being in Windows used unless the question indicates another C++ compiler. It's not reasonable to me to generally assert that "std::abort() is an immediate termination, but it is not an abnormal termination". It's not generally true, and it might have curtailed additional investigation to inquire about whether WER was actually restarting the application, which it will only do for an abnormal termination.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. I believe the explanation for the observed behavior makes sense, although it look like a severe limitation in the WER recovery callback mechanism. In order to run recovery code when std::abort is called, what is the recommended approach? I understand that avoiding such mechanism is best, but I'm working with legacy code here.

Comment: If a `SIGABRT` handler is set, it gets called before executing the default abort behavior. You could set a `SIGABRT` handler that intentionally causes an access violation or raises an exception via WinAPI `RaiseException`. In this case, WER will call the in-process recovery callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who helped answering this post. From the discussion, it appears that the recovery callback registered with RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback is intentionally not run when std::abort is called. A possible work-around is to call RaiseException from a `SIGABRT` handler.

Edit:
std::abort may boil down to a call to the __fastfail intrinsic, resulting in a non-continuable exception with exception code 0xC0000409. According to the [__fastfail documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/fastfail?view=vs-2019), this tells Windows Error Reporting that minimal in-process actions should be taken in response to the failure. Since the Application Recovery Callback is indeed an in-process action, it is reasonable for Windows Error Reporting to not call the callback when std::abort is called.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.